# implementing broadcast traffic restriction

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-asr, cisco-ios-xr, cisco-7600, asr

Can we restrict the high broadcast traffic from interface in Cisco ASR9k and 7600 routers? If so, what configuration we should apply?

Comment: Are you sure it is coming from the routers? Routers do not propagate broadcasts unless you have enabled `ip directed-broadcast` on an interface. The routers themselves would only use broadcast for ARP, but that would be necessary for the proper functioning of the network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply drop broadcast traffic. You need to locate the source(s) first, then you can filter appropriately - ideally close to the source. Better yet, identify the problem causing the broadcasts and fix it.

Of course, *technically* you can simply restrict broadcast frequency but that drops random frames and is highly prone to disturb your regular broadcast traffic, most prominently ARP.

Comment: It could limit it using storm control. But i agree with you.

Comment: @user56700 Yes, a broadcast storm is something different and must be controlled, even with significant drops. I didn't have the impression the OP was referring to that though.